# Subscriber Dependents table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Subscriber and Dependents

```
 Subscribers
 1 John
 2 Joe
 3 Jean
 4 Alan
 5 Elena

 Dependents
 1 John (Same Person)
 1 Betty
 1 Hannah
 3 Grey
 4 Sumen
 4 Kevin

SELECT * FROM Subscribers LEFT JOIN Dependents ON Subscribers.Id = Dependents.Id
```

This gives me

```
John, John
John, Betty
John, Hannah
Joe,
Jean, Grey
Alan, Sumen
Alan, Kevin
Elena
```

I would need:

```
John, John
John, Betty
John, Hannah
Joe
Jean (Added)
Jean, Grey
Alan (Added)
Alan, Sumen
Alan, Kevin
Elena
```

Basically I want the subscriber record to be independent on themselves if the dependent isn't themselves like John.  Joe, Jean, Alan, Elena will all have records not related to the dependents.

I would think I need something like this

```
 SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIBERS LEFT JOIN Dependents ON Subscribers.Id = Depedents.Id
 Where Subscribers.First_Name IS NOT Dependents.First_Name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't think of any way to do this without a union.

```
SELECT S.name as subscriber, D.name as dependent FROM Subscribers S left JOIN Dependents D ON S.Id = D.Id
    UNION 
    SELECT S.name as subscriber, D.name as dependent FROM Subscribers S left JOIN Dependents D ON S.name = D.name
    ORDER BY subscriber, dependent
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc7ba/11

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a UNION ALL [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc7ba/12):

```
SELECT s.Name AS subscriber, d.Name AS dependent
FROM Subscribers AS s
INNER JOIN Dependents AS d ON s.Id = d.Id

UNION ALL

SELECT s.Name, NULL
FROM Subscribers AS s
LEFT JOIN Dependents AS d ON s.Name = d.Name
WHERE d.Name IS NULL

ORDER BY subscriber, dependent
;
```

Basically, the first SELECT gets all the matches by `Id`, while the second one adds subscribers that have names not found in `dependents`.